# How to hide _id from find_and_modify() - MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm using Python - Pymongo to read and update some value in MongoDB.

```
sequence = db1.sequence.find_and_modify(query=({'name':'Seq_AlertId'}),fields={'value'}, update={"$inc": {'value': 1}},upsert= True, new = True)
```

Fields attribute seems to specify the fields to be returned. However,
I get "value" including "_id" field. How do I get rid of this?

This is how I get output:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('568f4926d9e87e0ea8e06db9'), u'value': 10021270}
{u'_id': ObjectId('568f4926d9e87e0ea8e06db9'), u'value': 10021271}
{u'_id': ObjectId('568f4926d9e87e0ea8e06db9'), u'value': 10021272}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after carefully reading through the documentation, I found this.

```
sequence = db1.sequence.find_and_modify(query=({'name':'Seq_AlertId'}),fields={'value':1,'_id':0}, update={"$inc": { 'value': 1}},upsert= True, new = True)
```

Output:

```
{u'value': 435}
{u'value': 436}
{u'value': 437}
{u'value': 438}
```